# nodejs - Dedicated workers library

Tags: node.js, child-process

I want to create a pool of N workers, and pass work to them over time.

I checked out [workerpool](https://github.com/josdejong/workerpool) and [workerfarm](https://github.com/rvagg/node-worker-farm) but from what I see, these create the worker when work is posted. I.e time lost when initializing the worker.

I could just use the `child_process` module to do this myself, but would then have to set up fair distribution too. Is there an already existing module that does this type of stuff? (create N workers at start time and post work to them)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built in cluster module, you can spin up N workers and pass work between them through messages.

https://gist.github.com/jpoehls/2232358